# Elasticsearch fails to index long custom date format

Tags: elasticsearch

For timestamps I am using the ISO format with zone ID included, defined as:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z['z']'
```

This format for example matches these two timestamps:

```
2015-02-20T09:46:56.336Z[UTC]
2015-02-20T10:46:55.221+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

For indexing data into elasticsearch I also defined this date format in a mapping like this (using elastic4s DSL):

```
create index indexName mappings {
  "/exampleType" as (
    "exampleField" typed DateType
  ) dynamicDateFormats "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z['z']'"
}
```

Basically this mapping works as expected but I experience problems when the formatted date string gets too long due to the zone ID. E. g. the above example

```
2015-02-20T09:46:56.336Z[UTC]
```

having 30 chars works fine, whereas

```
2015-02-20T10:46:55.221+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

having 44 chars fails to index with following error:

```
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot read numeric data larger than 32 chars
 at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.NumericTokenizer.incrementToken(NumericTokenizer.java:78) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.2.jar:na]
 at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:618) ~[lucene-core-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2 1634293 - mike - 2014-10-26 05:51:56]
 at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:359) ~[lucene-core-4.10.2.jar:4.10.2 1634293 - mike - 2014-10-26 05:51:56]
 ...
```

My question is if there's a way to get around this problem e. g. by means of configuration or if I am forced to change my date format to ensure that formatted dates do not exceed 32 chars.